# find elasticsearch aggregation count

Tags: java, elasticsearch

`searchRequestBuilder.addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("topCategoryFilter").field("category_id").size(AGGREGATION_SIZE)
    .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("subCategoryFilter").field("sub_category_id").size(AGGREGATION_SIZE)));`

above is the code I have done

I need to find out elasticsearch aggregation count. for example,
I searched for shoes and filters are generated based on it. In those filter eg there is 'Adidas', 'Nike' brand filters are there. I want to find out how many products are there for adidas or for Nike and want to show those results along with filter.
That is Filter should show me Adidas(100) Nike(300)
I am generating filters using aggregation of Elastic search. Also I am using Java API
how do I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try some code. Please add your attempt in question.

Comment: @Sanjeev no I have not attempted anything. I am not getting any API for it

Comment: What is the issue with your code. It looks fine.

Comment: how do I get doc_count in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet()
    StringTerms stringTerms = searchResponse?.getAggregations()?.getAsMap()?.get("topCategoryFilter")
    List<StringTerms.Bucket> bucketList = stringTerms?.getBuckets()
    for(StringTerms.Bucket bucket :bucketList){
        String key = bucket.getKey()
        Integer doc_count = (Integer)bucket.getDocCount()
    }
```

Hope this heps!!

Comment: What should I do for nested terms?